# jaguarjs-jsdoc fails with ReferenceError when using tutorials

Tags: templates, jsdoc

I'm getting the error `ReferenceError: filename is not defined` when I run jsdoc with juaguarjs as template against a config with tutorials.

There will be no error in case:
 - I run jsdoc with its default template
 - I run jsdoc with jaguarjs template but without tutorials config

**The structure of the project**

```
|-- tut
|     |-- tut1.md
|     +--tut1.json
|-- jsdocconf.json
+-- Gruntfile.js
```

**tut1.md**

```
# Title 1
Text text text
```

**tut1.json**

```
{
    "title": "Tutorial 1"
}
```

**jsdocconf.json**

```
{
    "tags": {
        "allowUnknownTags" : true
    },
    "templates": {
        "cleverLinks": true,
        "monospaceLinks": true,
        "default": {
            "outputSourceFiles" : true
        },
        "applicationName": "SaphirJS",
        "disqus": "",
        "googleAnalytics": "",
        "linenums": false
    }
}
```

**Gruntfile.js**

```
jsdoc: {
    all: {
        src: [
            './src/main/js/**/*.js',
        ],
        options: {
            destination: 'doc',
            tutorials: './tut',
            template : "node_modules/jaguarjs-jsdoc",
            configure : "jsdocconf.json",
        },
    }
},
```

**The full error stack is as follows:**

```
>> An error occurs in jsdoc process:
>> org.mozilla.javascript.EcmaError: ReferenceError: "filename" is not defined. (<eval'ed string>#1(Function)#51)
>>  at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.constructError(ScriptRuntime.java:3785)
>>  at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.constructError(ScriptRuntime.java:3763)
>>  at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.notFoundError(ScriptRuntime.java:3848)
>>  at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.nameOrFunction(ScriptRuntime.java:1847)
>>  at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.name(ScriptRuntime.java:1786)
>>  at org.mozilla.javascript.Interpreter.interpretLoop(Interpreter.java:1780)
>>  at script.anonymous(<eval'ed string>#1(Function):51)
>>  at org.mozilla.javascript.Interpreter.interpret(Interpreter.java:854)
>>  at org.mozilla.javascript.InterpretedFunction.call(InterpretedFunction.java:164)
>>  at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.applyOrCall(ScriptRuntime.java:2521)
>>  at org.mozilla.javascript.BaseFunction.execIdCall(BaseFunction.java:300)
>>  at org.mozilla.javascript.IdFunctionObject.call(IdFunctionObject.java:129)
>>  at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.callN(OptRuntime.java:86)
>>  at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.file__home_younes_ouadi_Workspace_Dev_Web_SaphirJS_doc_node_modules_grunt_jsdoc_node_modules_jsdoc_node_modules_underscore_underscore_js_21._c_anonymous_141(Unknown Source)
>>  at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.file__home_younes_ouadi_Workspace_Dev_Web_SaphirJS_doc_node_modules_grunt_jsdoc_node_modules_jsdoc_node_modules_underscore_underscore_js_21.call(Unknown Source)
>>  at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.applyOrCall(ScriptRuntime.java:2521)
>>  at org.mozilla.javascript.BaseFunction.execIdCall(BaseFunction.java:300)
>>  at org.mozilla.javascript.IdFunctionObject.call(IdFunctionObject.java:129)
>>  at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call2(OptRuntime.java:76)
>>  at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.file__home_younes_ouadi_Workspace_Dev_Web_SaphirJS_doc_node_modules_grunt_jsdoc_node_modules_jsdoc_lib_jsdoc_template_js_50._c_anonymous_3(Unknown Source)
>>  at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.file__home_younes_ouadi_Workspace_Dev_Web_SaphirJS_doc_node_modules_grunt_jsdoc_node_modules_jsdoc_lib_jsdoc_template_js_50.call(Unknown Source)
>>  at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call2(OptRuntime.java:76)
>>  at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.file__home_younes_ouadi_Workspace_Dev_Web_SaphirJS_doc_node_modules_grunt_jsdoc_node_modules_jsdoc_lib_jsdoc_template_js_50._c_anonymous_4(Unknown Source)
>>  at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.file__home_younes_ouadi_Workspace_Dev_Web_SaphirJS_doc_node_modules_grunt_jsdoc_node_modules_jsdoc_lib_jsdoc_template_js_50.call(Unknown Source)
>>  at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call2(OptRuntime.java:76)
>>  at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.file__home_younes_ouadi_Workspace_Dev_Web_SaphirJS_doc_node_modules_jaguarjs_jsdoc_publish_js_49._c_generateTutorial_33(Unknown Source)
>>  at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.file__home_younes_ouadi_Workspace_Dev_Web_SaphirJS_doc_node_modules_jaguarjs_jsdoc_publish_js_49.call(Unknown Source)
>>  at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.callName(OptRuntime.java:97)
>>  at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.file__home_younes_ouadi_Workspace_Dev_Web_SaphirJS_doc_node_modules_jaguarjs_jsdoc_publish_js_49._c_anonymous_35(Unknown Source)
>>  at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.file__home_younes_ouadi_Workspace_Dev_Web_SaphirJS_doc_node_modules_jaguarjs_jsdoc_publish_js_49.call(Unknown Source)
>>  at org.mozilla.javascript.NativeArray.iterativeMethod(NativeArray.java:1563)
>>  at org.mozilla.javascript.NativeArray.execIdCall(NativeArray.java:345)
>>  at org.mozilla.javascript.IdFunctionObject.call(IdFunctionObject.java:129)
>>  at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call1(OptRuntime.java:66)
>>  at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.file__home_younes_ouadi_Workspace_Dev_Web_SaphirJS_doc_node_modules_jaguarjs_jsdoc_publish_js_49._c_saveChildren_34(Unknown Source)
>>  at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.file__home_younes_ouadi_Workspace_Dev_Web_SaphirJS_doc_node_modules_jaguarjs_jsdoc_publish_js_49.call(Unknown Source)
>>  at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.callName(OptRuntime.java:97)
>>  at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.file__home_younes_ouadi_Workspace_Dev_Web_SaphirJS_doc_node_modules_jaguarjs_jsdoc_publish_js_49._c_anonymous_23(Unknown Source)
>>  at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.file__home_younes_ouadi_Workspace_Dev_Web_SaphirJS_doc_node_modules_jaguarjs_jsdoc_publish_js_49.call(Unknown Source)
>>  at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.callN(OptRuntime.java:86)
>>  at org.mozilla.javascript.gen._home_younes_ouadi_Workspace_Dev_Web_SaphirJS_doc_node_modules_grunt_jsdoc_node_modules_jsdoc_jsdoc_js_1._c_main_3(Unknown Source)
>>  at org.mozilla.javascript.gen._home_younes_ouadi_Workspace_Dev_Web_SaphirJS_doc_node_modules_grunt_jsdoc_node_modules_jsdoc_jsdoc_js_1.call(Unknown Source)
>>  at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.callName0(OptRuntime.java:108)
>>  at org.mozilla.javascript.gen._home_younes_ouadi_Workspace_Dev_Web_SaphirJS_doc_node_modules_grunt_jsdoc_node_modules_jsdoc_jsdoc_js_1._c_script_0(Unknown Source)
>>  at org.mozilla.javascript.gen._home_younes_ouadi_Workspace_Dev_Web_SaphirJS_doc_node_modules_grunt_jsdoc_node_modules_jsdoc_jsdoc_js_1.call(Unknown Source)
>>  at org.mozilla.javascript.ContextFactory.doTopCall(ContextFactory.java:426)
>>  at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.doTopCall(ScriptRuntime.java:3178)
>>  at org.mozilla.javascript.gen._home_younes_ouadi_Workspace_Dev_Web_SaphirJS_doc_node_modules_grunt_jsdoc_node_modules_jsdoc_jsdoc_js_1.call(Unknown Source)
>>  at org.mozilla.javascript.gen._home_younes_ouadi_Workspace_Dev_Web_SaphirJS_doc_node_modules_grunt_jsdoc_node_modules_jsdoc_jsdoc_js_1.exec(Unknown Source)
>>  at org.mozilla.javascript.tools.shell.Main.evaluateScript(Main.java:654)
>>  at org.mozilla.javascript.tools.shell.Main.processFileSecure(Main.java:552)
>>  at org.mozilla.javascript.tools.shell.Main.processFile(Main.java:507)
>>  at org.mozilla.javascript.tools.shell.Main.processSource(Main.java:499)
>>  at org.mozilla.javascript.tools.shell.Main.processFiles(Main.java:215)
>>  at org.mozilla.javascript.tools.shell.Main$IProxy.run(Main.java:134)
>>  at org.mozilla.javascript.Context.call(Context.java:521)
>>  at org.mozilla.javascript.ContextFactory.call(ContextFactory.java:535)
>>  at org.mozilla.javascript.tools.shell.Main.exec(Main.java:198)
>>  at org.mozilla.javascript.tools.shell.Main.main(Main.java:174)
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, and solved it.

The eval'd string gets eval'd by underscore's template method. This is used to interpret the < ? js = templating inside the templates used in jaguarjs-jsdoc (see the files in the tmpl directory).

Upon inspecting these files, you'll see layout.tmpl uses the (unbound) variable filename. This variable, as underscore's template's method's documentation teaches us, will get filled in by a property of the same name on the object that gets passed to the generated method.
When looking at jaguarjs-jsdoc's publish.js, you'll notice the objects that get passed as final argument to the render method calls have a filename property set for the non-tutorial rendering. In the tutorial rendering, this filename property is not set. Just add it to the tutorialData object that gets defined at around publish.js:493. I'm just raising an issue with them.

Comment: Good work `@Anon`. I hope the developers will react to your analysis.
In fact, they are not responding. This issue is already reported to them many times (see `https://github.com/davidshimjs/jaguarjs-jsdoc/issues/29` and `https://github.com/davidshimjs/jaguarjs-jsdoc/issues/15`).
As such, I have moved to `docstrap`. The template is good and come with many `theme` to choose from.